# Is the following position a win for White or a draw?

Tags: analysis

The deceptively simple 11 piece position is hard to decifrate. In a Sicilian Defense, Paulsen variation, the following position appeared on the board: Grandellius vs Andreikin, Black to move. What happens with perfect play?

```
    [FEN "8/1R4bk/4p1p1/4Pr2/7P/4BPK1/8/8 b - - 0 1"]
```

Comment: I'm tempted to say this is a draw, but can provide no proof

Comment: I'd play Kg8 instinctively. So does Stockfish. With increasing depth, the value goes up and up, confirming my gut feeling that the position is hard to defend (good bishops don't defend bad pawns - this means you, e6!). In the meantime, +5 and Black didn't lose a pawn yet. So, I'm tempted to say, Rubinstein or Carlsen win this for White.